# SSD Becomes Unbootable after a few Days

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd

As Mr. Atwood [wrote this week](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html), I need to come to accept that my [SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820227660) will be a little problematic, as seems to be norm for this generation of drives. My motherboard is an [X58 Sabertooth](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131665R), and I'm running Windows 7.

This morning, when I rebooted, Windows informed me that it could not load. This is after I reinstalled it about a week ago. What can I do to increase the time between failures?

Answer (score 6):

You buy a more reliable drive than OCZ.

A more practical suggestion probably is to make sure that garbage collection/TRIM/whatever your drive needs is running properly.  **There's no reason a default installation of Windows 7 should not work fine, in AHCI mode, on any SSD indefinitely without failure.**  Either there's something wrong with the drive or there's something independent that's gotten damaged in the installation.

Comment: OCZ's do have a pretty high failure rate...

Comment: could you be more specific on what you mean by "garbage collection/TRIM/whatever"? I found an article on Wikipedia that explains it, but no specific steps I should take, given my hardware.

Comment: This is something that will vary with your drive.  I think the drive in question does automatic garbage collection, so you should be fine on that front, but I'm not 100% on that.  Really, running in AHCI rather than IDE mode (and ensuring your partitions are properly aligned, which if you made them under Windows 7 they are so I didn't mention it) are the biggest factors.